# How to create a HeaderFooter object in Flutter using Excel package?

Tags: excel, flutter

I am creating an Excel file in Flutter using the pub.dev package Excel. Here is the doc page for the HeaderFooter object [https://pub.dev/documentation/excel/latest/excel/HeaderFooter-class.html](https://stackoverflow.com). On all the types of headers as arguments, they all are String?. I had assumed that would be the text for the type of header. But no, MS Excel says the file is corrupt. I produced a XLSX file in Excel with a header and examined the XML file for the sheet I created. The tags were the same, but the "string" is not the text of the header, but some cryptic information with some font information embedded. Back to Flutter, what should that String value represent? I've searched high & low for examples with no luck. BTW - this is using version 2.1.0 of Excel package.